# How can I see a custom symbol on ProViewer?

Tags: symbology, mapinfo

I loaded the symbol to Mapinfo and used it in a workspace. I copied the symbol to the ProViewer and restarted the computer, but I can't see the symbols when I open the workspace on ProViewer.

Comment: Where did you copy the symbol to?

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\MapInfo\Proviewer\AddUser\CustSymb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Custom Symbols need to be copied to the AppData folder for the specific application.

You can find the folder in this way.

1. In Windows Explorer type this in the address lines followed by hitting Enter:

   %AppData%
2. Now go into the MapInfo folder
3. And no go into the ProViewer folder
4. Go into the specific version you are using
5. Here you should see the CustSymb folder where you should copy the image files to.

For my MapInfo Pro v15.2 the full path is:
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\MapInfo\MapInfo\Professional\1520\CustSymb
where  is my Windows User login.

[image]

Note that MapInfo Professional might have more files and folders in this folder than a MapInfo ProViewer will have.